# Refactor/compose decoders

Tags: scala, circe

Given:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime
import io.circe.{Decoder, HCursor}
import io.circe.derivation.{deriveDecoder, renaming}

object Configuration {
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Configuration] = deriveDecoder(renaming.snakeCase)
}
case class Configuration(maxVersions: Int = 10, casRequired: Boolean = false)

case class Metadata(
  createdTime: OffsetDateTime,
  updatedTime: OffsetDateTime,
  currentVersion: Int,
  oldestVersion: Int,
  configuration: Configuration
)
```

I want to implement a `Decoder[Metadata]` but there is a catch, the Json for it **isn't**:

```
{
  "created_time": "2018-03-22T02:24:06.945319214Z",
  "updated_time": "2018-03-22T02:24:06.945319214Z",
  "current_version": 5,
  "oldest_version": 1,
  "configuration" {
    "max_versions": 10,
    "cas_required": true
  }
}
```

But rather:

```
{
  "created_time": "2018-03-22T02:24:06.945319214Z",
  "updated_time": "2018-03-22T02:24:06.945319214Z",
  "current_version": 5,
  "oldest_version": 1,
  "max_versions": 10,
  "cas_required": true
}
```

I can create this decoder manually with:

```
implicit val decoder: Decoder[Metadata] = (cursor: HCursor) => for {
  createdTime <- cursor.get[OffsetDateTime]("created_time")
  updatedTime <- cursor.get[OffsetDateTime]("updated_time")
  currentVersion <- cursor.get[Int]("current_version")
  oldestVersion <- cursor.get[Int]("oldest_version")
  configuration <- cursor.as[Configuration]
} yield Metadata(createdTime, updatedTime, currentVersion, oldestVersion, configuration)
```

However I'm not being DRY most of this logic would already be implemented by `deriveDecoder[Metadata](renaming.snakeCase)`.

My question is, how can I implement the decoder in the following code using the `derivedDecoder` to do the heavy lifting:

```
object Metadata {
  private val derivedDecoder = deriveDecoder[Metadata](renaming.snakeCase)
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Metadata] = ???
}
```

I found a working, but **inefficient** and ugly, solution:

```
implicit val decoder: Decoder[Metadata] = (cursor: HCursor) => for {
  configuration <- cursor.as[Configuration]
  metadata <- cursor.value.mapObject(_.add("configuration", configuration.asJson)).as[Metadata](derivedDecoder)
} yield metadata
```